# Tess4j - Searchable PDF

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am able to extract the text from images or extract the images out of a pdf and then to ocr to get the text - but I want to create a searchable pdf out of images or a pdf with images in it.
It must somehow work with ITessAPI (TessAPI1 or Tesseract1) but I don't know how to start here correctly.

Edit:

```
public void doOcr(String tessDataPath, String imagePath) throws IOException {
    int set_only_init_params = FALSE;
    int oem = ITessAPI.TessOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT;
    PointerByReference configs = null;
    int configs_size = 0;

    String[] params = {"load_system_dawg", "tessedit_char_whitelist"};
    String vals[] = {"F", ""}; //0123456789-.IThisalotfpnex
    //PointerByReference vars_vec = new PointerByReference();
    //vars_vec.setPointer(new Pointer(params));
    //PointerByReference vars_values = new PointerByReference();
    //vars_values.setPointer(new StringArray(vals));
    NativeSize vars_vec_size = new NativeSize(params.length);

    TessAPI1 api = new TessAPI1();
    ITessAPI.TessBaseAPI handle = api.TessBaseAPICreate();

    int rc = api.TessBaseAPIInit4(handle, tessDataPath, "eng", oem, configs, configs_size, null, null, vars_vec_size, set_only_init_params);
    api.TessBaseAPISetVariable(handle, "user_defined_dpi", "270");

    if (rc != 0) {
        api.TessBaseAPIDelete(handle);
        //logger.error("Could not initialize tesseract.");
        return;
    }

    String outputbase = "C:\\Application\\ResultRenderer";
    ITessAPI.TessResultRenderer renderer = api.TessHOcrRendererCreate(outputbase);
    api.TessResultRendererInsert(renderer, api.TessBoxTextRendererCreate(outputbase));
    api.TessResultRendererInsert(renderer, api.TessTextRendererCreate(outputbase));
    String dataPath = api.TessBaseAPIGetDatapath(handle);
    api.TessResultRendererInsert(renderer, api.TessPDFRendererCreate(outputbase, dataPath, FALSE));
    int result = api.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(handle, imagePath, null, 0, renderer);

    if (result == FALSE) {
        //logger.error("Error during processing.");
        return;
    }

    while ((renderer = api.TessResultRendererNext(renderer)) != null) {
        String ext = api.TessResultRendererExtention(renderer).getString(0);
        String log = String.format("TessResultRendererExtention: %s\nTessResultRendererTitle: %s\nTessResultRendererImageNum: %d",
                ext,
                api.TessResultRendererTitle(renderer).getString(0),
                api.TessResultRendererImageNum(renderer));
    }

    api.TessDeleteResultRenderer(renderer);
    api.TessBaseAPIEnd(handle);

    File ocrPdf = new File(outputbase + ".pdf");
    if (!ocrPdf.exists()) {
        // TODO
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i found a way but I have the problem that the generated PDF now have the following issues:
Compliance pdf1.5
Result Document does not conform to PDF/A.
Details 

Validating file "ResultRenderer.pdf" for conformance level pdf1.5

The embedded font program 'GlyphLessFont' cannot be read.

The document does not conform to the requested standard.

The document contains fonts without embedded font programs or encoding information (CMAPs).

The document does not conform to the PDF 1.5 standard.